# Unable to access the data members in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am calling make a http get request but when I try to access the data members of the result I get the below error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'.

Below is the code snippet. Kindly do let me know, if I am doing anything wrong.

**employee.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  baseUrl = 'https://69cfe870-af8a-4764-b133-67f93e11170c.mock.pstmn.io/employeeList';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    get_employees() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }
}
```

employee.ts

```
export class Employee {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
}
```

Below is my component.ts file. In `ngOnInit` method when I try to access `data[1].name` member, I am getting  `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'`

employee.component.ts

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private EmployeeService : employeeService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.employeeService.get_employees().
    subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data[1].name);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: can you please check your console? any error are there?

Comment: core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (clientslist.component.ts:36)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:72)

Comment: Are you sure `data` has at least 2 elements? Could you `console.log(data)` before `console.log(data[1].name)`?

Comment: Even for console.log(data[0].name), it is throwing the same error. And when I print console.log(data) It shows {Employee: Array(2)} in the console.

Comment: If I try the link you have provided i get below response `{"error":{"name":"mockRequestNotFoundError","message":"Double check your method and the request path and try again.","header":"No matching requests"}}`

Comment: I think in your case it is coming as string so use the JSON.parse function, then it will available as object.

Comment: Can you add only the console.log of `console.log(data)` without going to the first Object, maybe then we will help you.
Maybe the `data[1].name ` does not exist that why is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server might be returning you an array with less than 2 entries, in which case `data[1]`would be `undfined` because [JavaScript arrays are 0-indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#accessing_array_elements).